# Cannot Login at MailGun

Tags: authentication, mailgun, django-mailgun

Whenever I login in Mailgun with my Account it says "Bad email or password" eventhough the email is already activated and the password is correct. I already created a second MailGun account and when I tried to log it out, I also cannot log in back again!

Comment: Does anyone know the troubleshoot am also facing the same  issue. Did you fine the answer for it @Dale Lanto